# Finding and clicking an check box that is part of the jstree using xpath?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jstree

I am trying to click a checkbox that is part of the jstree and every thing i have tried so far has been unsuccessful. Please assist. **The goal is to check the checkbox where the id is 733**

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="jstree-1" class="jstree jstree-2 jstree-default jstree-default-responsive jstree-checkbox-no-clicked" role="tree" aria-activedescendant="8528">
<ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-no-dots jstree-no-icons">
    <li id="733" class="jstree-node jstree-open jstree-last" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true">
        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"/>
        <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox"/>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon false jstree-themeicon-custom"/>
            Accepts Cash
        </a>
        <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to click on the checkbox, present in jstree using selenium webdriver with JAVA.

Here are things i have tried so far without success.

Solution 1:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@id = '733']/a/i[@class = 'jstree-icon jstree-checkbox']")).click();
```

Solution 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("733")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```

Solution 3:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='733']/a/i[1]"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Solution 4:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='733']/a/i[1]")).click();
```

All the commands are followed by the following line

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And i keep on getting the below error code:

```
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (695, 507). Other element would receive the click: <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">...</a>
```

This is what happens after executing all the given solutions:

[Dropdown box opens up but is not getting clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpPdi.png)

[After checkbox is clicked in frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvYZC.png)

The following line of code is added to the HTML:

```
<span class="selectedCount" data-count="4"> (4)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to click on `<i>`, while really the `<a>` is clickable. Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@id='733']/a")).click();
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, i have attached an image to display the end result, the drop down box is opened but the checkbox is never selected.

Comment: how does the HTML change when the element is checked?

Comment: @maxshaw I faced similar issue where i need to click on a tab to get more options and select one option and click on it. I had to use driver.find_element_by_xpath().click() twice with the id of two buttons one after another.

Comment: I added the extra line of HTML that comes up after i click, the checkbox. Kiril, apologies.

Comment: @Vivek tried that also but to no luck, the drop down box is expanded, but the check box is never selected, please refer to the two attached images.